# Align Bootstrap input box and button on same row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap, if I have an input box with label and button in the same row, how do I get the button to align? I don't want to append it to the input box using input-append - any ideas?

```
                    <div class="row">

                            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                                <label for="txtSchedFromDate">
                                    From:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="txtSchedFromDate" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                                <label for="txtSchedToDate">
                                    To:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="txtSchedToDate" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                                <button type="button" id="btnResetEngineers" class="btn btn-default">
                                        Reset Engineers</button>
                            </div>

                    </div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ax63bu3e/)

Many thanks

Comment: Check out the documentation section on inline-forms http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Schmalzy - I've added the form inline but and played around with the form and input groups but it still puts the button inline with the label and not the input box - this does depend on the size of the screen - it works if I get rid of the label which i was going to do and use the placeholder instead but that doesn't work in IE9 :-\

Comment: Hmm, if I remove the column sizing it works - i'd still prefer the labels to be on top of the input fields rather than to the side but i will have to make do - thanks again

Answer (score 0):

These are the changes I have made
Just include form-control in the button class and an empty label for the button's div

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-3">
  <label for="txtSchedFromDate">
    &nbsp;
  </label>
  <button type="button" id="btnResetEngineers" class="form-control btn btn-default">Reset Engineers</button>
</div>
```

Here's a corrected fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Indu9594/rcwyso3x/